# How do you video the mobile app?

Tags: android, video, emulation, android-sdk-tools

When I look up some [awesome android libraries](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui) I see that nearly all are using some cool quality gifs to show off the features. So my question is - how do you film the app and make it into a gif? What software and techniques are involved?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* ... most modern devices have possibility of screen recording ... then you use any program to convert mp4 to animated gif ... that's it

Comment: You could also look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine to record your screen

Comment: I'm not asking recommendation of what software to use. I am just wondering how to do this in not a daft and free way

Answer (score 1):

upload your video or images onto this site and it will change it to a gif.

http://gifmaker.me/

Answer (score 1):

Mobile version:
Gifboom is a good gif maker app
You can find out good apps to make a gif using https://www.lifewire.com/free-gif-maker-apps-for-iphone-and-android-3486328

or make a gif online:
https://giphy.com/create/gifmaker
This website is simple and easy to use